# Access photos without password Windows 10

Tags: windows

My mom forgot her password, and she can’t log in to her laptop now. Is there a way for us to get our family pictures? That’s the only thing we really want to recover. I’m not a Windows user, so I’m clueless; any suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: Yes, you can get the pictures. If you don't know how to do it, take it to a technician who will help you for a (hopefully reasonable) fee. But this is really not a question for this site, sorry!

Comment: @joanis We finally did it, so thank you for closing the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the windows account is connected to a Microsoft account, the password can be reset through Microsoft directly (i.e outlook.com).

However, I am not aware of a simple way to reset the password of a local user on windows.

An alternative that may work would be to boot from a Linux live USB (DO NOT INSTALL from the USB) and access the files on the disks from there.

Comment: This suggestion worked, thanks a lot!